# `category` and `tag` shared by multiple wagtail page types

Tags: many-to-many, categories, wagtail, django-taggit

I have a Django+Wagtail website, and have `category` and `tag` created to be applied to blog posts.

```
from taggit.models import Tag as TaggitTag
from taggit.models import TaggedItemBase

class PostList(RoutablePageMixin, Page):
    template = "Post_List.html"
    intro = RichTextField(blank=True)
    content_panels = Page.content_panels + [
        FieldPanel("intro")
        ]

    subpage_types = [
        "PostDetail",
    ]

    parent_page_type = [
        "HomePage",
    ]

    # Each 'search / category / tag / author' will generate a separate 'PostList' page with its own 'context', 
    # hence for 'Pagination' for all 'PostList' pages, we only need to implement in 'get_context()'
    def get_context(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context(request, *args, **kwargs)

        # For Pagination
        page_id = request.GET.get("page")
        paginator = Paginator(self.posts, 3)   # 'posts' is defined in 'def post_list()' and 'def get_posts()' as below.
        try:
            paginator_page = paginator.page(page_id)
        except PageNotAnInteger:
            paginator_page = paginator.page(1)
            page_id = 1
        except EmptyPage:
            paginator_page = paginator.page(1)
            page_id =1

        context['paginator_page'] = paginator_page           
        context['total_num_pages'] = paginator.num_pages

        # By default, Paginator.get_elided_page_range(number, *, on_each_side=3, on_ends=2)
        context['elided_page_range'] = paginator.get_elided_page_range(page_id, on_each_side=5, on_ends=2)  
        return context

    def get_posts(self):
        return PostDetail.objects.descendant_of(self).live()


    @route(r'^tag/(?P<tag>[-\w]+)/$')
    def post_by_tag(self, request, tag, *args, **kwargs):
        self.search_type = 'tag'
        self.search_term = tag
        self.posts = self.get_posts().filter(tags__name=tag)
        return Page.serve(self, request, *args, **kwargs)

    @route(r'^category/(?P<category>[-\w]+)/$')
    def post_by_category(self, request, category, *args, **kwargs):
        self.search_type = 'category'
        self.search_term = category
        self.posts = self.get_posts().filter(categories__category__name=category)
        return Page.serve(self, request, *args, **kwargs)

    @route(r'^user/(?P<user>[-\w]+)/$')
    def post_by_user(self, request, user, *args, **kwargs):
        self.search_type = 'user'
        self.search_term = user
        self.posts = self.get_posts().filter(owner__username=user)
        return Page.serve(self, request, *args, **kwargs)

    @route(r'^$')
    def post_list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.posts = self.get_posts()
        return Page.serve(self, request, *args, **kwargs)

    @route(r'^search/$')
    def post_search(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        search_query = request.GET.get('q', None)
        self.posts = self.get_posts()
        if search_query:
            self.posts = self.posts.filter(body__contains=search_query)
            self.search_term = search_query
            self.search_type = 'search'
        return Page.serve(self, request, *args, **kwargs)

class PostDetail(Page):
    template = "Post_Detail.html"
    
    body = MarkdownField()
    tags = ClusterTaggableManager(through="PostDetailTag", blank=True)


@register_snippet
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True, max_length=100)

    panels = [
        FieldPanel("name"),
        FieldPanel("slug"),
    ]

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Category"
        verbose_name_plural = "Categories"
        ordering = ["name"]


@register_snippet
class Tag(TaggitTag):
    class Meta:
        proxy = True
        
# Intermediate Models for ManyToMany Relationship
class PostDetailCategory(models.Model):
    post = ParentalKey("PostDetail", on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="categories")
    category = models.ForeignKey("Category", on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="post_details")

    panels = [
        SnippetChooserPanel("category"),
    ]

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ("post", "category")

class PostDetailTag(TaggedItemBase):
    content_object = ParentalKey("PostDetail", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Now, I am about to creating another wagtail page type "SurveyPoll", and want to have `tag` and `category` applied as well.
**What is the best practice for this deployment, same `tag` and `category` applied to different wagtail page types via `ManyToMany` relationship ?**

**Which type of `ManyToMany` relationship deployment is better, `tag` or `category` ? Personally, I prefer the `category` way as it allows me to choose from a list of existing `category` in wagtail admin edit page.**

Comment: This will be very hard to answer as it is based on opinion and requires a full understanding of your goals. This kind of question is probably not really suited to the Stackoverflow format. How you want to model your tags/categories really depends on how you want your site to work. If you want to share categories across page types, do that, otherwise set up new categories for each page type. In general though - simpler is better until you need more complex things.

Comment: Django has something called [generic relations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#generic-relations), which allow you to link a tag or category to any model you want.